# TCP Client/Server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have this code and for some reason it stucks at readline() line at servers end always waiting from client but client on the other end sends the data.

Both the server and client's code is available below.

## Server Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPServer {
  public static final int SERVER_PORT = 6789;

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;

    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

    while (true) {
      Socket connectSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
      InputStream sin = connectSocket.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sin));

      PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter(connectSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

      capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + "\r\n";

      outToClient.print(capitalizedSentence);
    }
  }
}
```

## Client Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    String hostName = "localhost";
    int port = 6789;
    String sentence; 
    String modifiedSentence; 

    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);

    PrintWriter outToServer =  null;
    clientSocket.getOutputStream();

    BufferedReader inFromServer = null;
    inFromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    sentence = inFromUser.readLine(); 
    outToServer.print(sentence + "\r\n");

    modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " +modifiedSentence); 
    clientSocket.close(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it stucks at clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine(); although client sends the required sentence

Comment: This can't possibly compile; it has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: there are no unbalanced parentheses i have successfully compiled it.

Comment: @JimGarrison: It was probably just copy/paste issue. I've tidied up the code a bit.

Comment: @user1467270: The code you pasted had an extraneous `,true);`, which was what Jim mentioned would not compile. Jim was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing your syntax errors around `outToServer`, I think the problem lies in the way you're using `PrintWriter` around the output stream on the client's side. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will
>   be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is
>   invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be
>   output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator
>   rather than the newline character.

Since you're using `print` with a manually appended new line, the message is never flushed to the socket's output stream. I believe you can fix this by using `println` instead:

```
outToServer.println(sentence);
```

Even better would be to use `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` instead of `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`, as those are better suited for sending and receiving arbitrary data over a socket stream.

Comment: Yes perfect it helped, thankyou. and i think you meant 
    outToServer.println(sentence);

Comment: Yup, typo. I strongly suggest you start using `DataInputStream` / `DataOutputStream` though. `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter` are better suited when dealing with text files or an error stream of some kind.

Comment: Well yes i am actually working with text files so thats why i'm using 'PrintWritter'